# Timer compilation issue

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am trying to run a small example which i found from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html . However, I get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Timer` on the timer = new Timer..... line. I was hoping someone could help me.

```
  int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Thank you

my code;

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class MyTimerTest 
{
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    Timer timer;
    int delay = 1000; //a second

    public MyTimerTest()
    {
    }


    public void runTimer()
    {
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }     
        };

        timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the *complete* code you're trying. There could be any number of reasons why this is failing, but they require more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not contain line `timer = ...`. 
I believe you tried to write:

`Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();`

This cannot be compiled because method `start()` is void.

Just separate this line into 2:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
timer.start();
```

EDIT, oh, my assumption is correct. I just have not seen the second line where you are using timer in the second fragment of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add Swing Timer

```
import javax.swing.Timer

    public void runTimer()
    {
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }     
        };

        timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer).start();
    }
```